# What is the app_id and secret_key for Koala Facebook Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I can't seem to figure this part out. I understand this is a severely dumb question :D

Anyone know where I can find my app_id and secret_key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Go to this page. Register your Web Application using their forms.

At completion, you will be provided with an App ID and Secret ID